# Even the file system is full, Then to linux system will work fine. How it is happening?

Tags: linux

Even the file system is full, Then to linux system will work fine. How it is happening ?

Answer (score 1):

check your disk is full

```
df -h
```

maybe one of your partition is full, and others not